# Unable to display data in my react native table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a react native table component which calls an api for some data. When I try to display the data in the render method I get an error:

```
undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')
- node_modules\react-native-table-component\components\rows.js:17:6 in Row#render
```

I am able to display the data using static data, issue only occurs when I try to use data from api, see code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import axios from 'axios';
const url = 'http://strong-bullfrog-42.serverless.social/api/players';



class TableComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: [],
            }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                    let players = res.data.players.map(player => {
                    return {
                        name: player.name,
                        played: player.gamesPlayed,
                        w: player.wins,
                        d: player.draws,
                        l: player.losses,
                        goals: player.goalsScored,
                        assists: player.assists
                    }
                });
               this.setState({data: players} );
                })
           }

    render() 
        const tableHead = ['Name', 'P', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'GS', 'A'];
        const widthArr = [70, 60, 30, 50, 40, 40, 40];
        const state = this.state;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                    <View>
                        <Table borderStyle={{borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
                            <Row data={tableHead} widthArr={widthArr} style={styles.header} textStyle={styles.headerText}/>
                        </Table>
                        <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
                            <Table borderStyle={{borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
                                <Rows data={state.data} flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} widthArr={widthArr} style={styles.row}
                                textStyle={styles.text}/>
                            </Table>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },
    header: { height: 50, backgroundColor: '#77abb7' },
    text: { textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: '100', color: '#000000' },
    headerText: { textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff' },
    dataWrapper: { marginTop: -1 },
    row: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#E7E6E1' }
});

export default TableComponent;
```

I'm a react newbie and I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: whats the value of your state variable when you get the error ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan: When I console log the state.data in the render method this is what I'm getting:```[
    {
        "name": "Bealini",
        "played": 28,
        "w": 3,
        "d": 0,
        "l": 1,
        "goals": 55,
        "assists": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Joe Exotic",
        "played": 45,
        "w": 3,
        "d": 0,
        "l": 1,
        "goals": 29,
        "assists": 240
    }
]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are sending objects to data prop of Rows where it expects an array of arrays. This is why you are getting the .map is not a function as the library is trying to use the map function of your object that you are passing.
The easiest fix would be changing the mapper of the axios success function like below.

```
let players = res.data.players.map(player => {
return [
    player.name,
    player.gamesPlayed,
    player.wins,
    player.draws,
    player.losses,
    player.goalsScored,
    player.assists
]});
```